# reduce dataframe -> obtaining last row for every level in column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I would like to reduce my dataframe as follows:

[image]

The only last row of all levels in the column "Step_ID" should be stored.
Is there any way, how to automate the process?

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Step_ID': ["Step1", "Step1", "Step1", "Step2", "Step2", "Step3", "Step3", "Step3", "Step3"],    
        'value_01': [2, 2.3, 2.2, 0, 0, 5, 5.2, 5, 5.2]}  
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates('Step_ID', keep='last')`

Comment: Thank you guys. It works perfectly. Henry, you are my life-saver! Sorry, i forgot to paste the "code".